# iOS keyboard is showing two "Done" buttons in toolbar but I only have one - Swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hi and sorry if its a dumb question.

I have been following HackingWithSwift SwiftUI tutorial day 19([link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/hiding-the-keyboard))
but I am facing a problem. I tried to use `.focus()` modifier and a boolean to handle a button and hide my keyboard when user press done. Whenever I am trying to hide my keyboard I have 2 'Done' buttons even though I just added one to my UI and even when I remove that one button it wont show no "Done" button at all and I can't hide my keyboard.

Note: I tried it on Preview and iPhone Simulator but not on a physical device.

I added a screenshot and code as well.

Here is my code:

```
//  ContentView.swift
//  WeSplit


import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var checkAmount = 0.0
    @State private var numberOfPeople = 2
    @State private var tipPercentage = 20
    @FocusState private var amountIsFocused: Bool
    
    let tipPercentages = [10, 15, 20, 25, 0]
    
    //For Total cost + tip
    var grandTotal: Double{
        let tipSelection = Double(tipPercentage)
        let tipValue = checkAmount / 100 * tipSelection
        let grandTotal = checkAmount + tipValue
        
        return grandTotal
    }
    
    
    //For individual share
    var totalPerPerson: Double{
        let peopleCount = Double(numberOfPeople + 2)
        let amountPerPerson = grandTotal / peopleCount
    
        return amountPerPerson
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form{
                Section{
                    TextField("Amount: ", value: $checkAmount, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "USD"))
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        .focused($amountIsFocused)
                    
                    Picker("Number of people", selection: $numberOfPeople){
                        ForEach(2..<100){
                            Text("\($0) people")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Section{
                    Picker("Tip Percentage", selection: $tipPercentage){
                        ForEach(tipPercentages, id:\.self){
                            Text($0, format: .percent)
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
                                        
                }header: {
                    Text("How much tip do you want to leave?")
                }
                
                
                //Grand Total
                Section{
                    Text(grandTotal, format:.currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "USD"))
                }header: {
                    Text("Total Cost + Tip")
                }
                
                
                //Showing each person's share
                Section{
                    Text(totalPerPerson, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "USD"))
                }header: {
                    Text("Amount Per Person")
                }.navigationTitle("WeSplit")
                    .toolbar(){
                        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard){
                            
                            Button("Done"){
                                amountIsFocused = false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                
                
                
            
            }
        }
    }
        
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image: ScreenShot of my ios simulator]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is here:

```
.toolbar(){
```

Test that without parenthesis:

```
.toolbar {
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the "toolbar" block out of "Form". I don't know why it works but it does. [Attaching a screenshot of how it looks after the change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHR7H.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **ToolbarItem(id: ...)** but be aware that it captures a single state, so it is not possible to reset different FocusStates or know which field should be reset, or at least I did not find the way how to do it.

```
struct FocusCancellable: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(id: "_KeyboardDoneButton", placement: .keyboard) {
                    Button(action: {
                        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                    }) {
                        Text("Done")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    public func focusCancellable() -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: FocusCancellable())
    }
}
```